# Best way to change words into numbers using specific word list

Tags: python, regex, sed, awk

I have a text file that contains tweets per line, that need to be altered for a machine learning format. Im using python and basic unix text manipulation (regex) to achieve a lot of my string manipulation, and im gettin the hang of sed, grep and pythons .re function....this next problem however is mindblower for me, and wondering if anyone could help me with this. I have tried a few google searches, but tbh no luck :(

I always start with pseudocode to make it easier on me, and this is what i want...
"*Replace -token1- OR -token2- OR -token3- OR -token4- with integer '1', replace all **other** words/tokens with integer '0'* "

Lets say my list of words/tokens for which need to become '1' is the following:

- :)
- cool
- happy
- fun

and my tweets look like this:

- this has been a fun day :)
- i find python cool! it makes me happy

The output of the new program/function would be:

- 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
- 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1

NOTE1: Notice how 'cool' has a '!' behind it, it should be included as well, although i can always remove all punctuation in the file first, to make it easier

NOTE2: All tweets will be lowercase, I already have a function that changes all the lines into lowercase

Does anyone know how to do this using unix regex (such as sed, grep, awk) or even how to do it in python? BTW this is NOT homework, im working on a sentiment analysis program and am experimenting a bit.

thanx! :)

Comment: How do you want those zeros and ones? String or int array? Wouldn't you want to count sorts of total based on amount of words and relative strength of certain words/tokens?

Comment: I think the example is inconsistent. "`cool!`" is not in the list (but "`cool`" is). Should exclamation marks be treated specially (eg. ignored)? What are the rules regarding that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from string import punctuation as pnc
tokens = {':)', 'cool', 'happy', 'fun'}
tweets = ['this has been a fun day :)', 'i find python cool! it makes me happy']
for tweet in tweets:
    s = [(word in tokens or word.strip(pnc) in tokens) for word in tweet.split()]
    print(' '.join('1' if t else '0' for t in s))
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

The `or` in the 4th line is there to handle `:)`, as suggested by @EOL.

There are still cases that will not be handled correctly, such as with `cool :), I like it`. The problem is inherent to the requirements.

Comment: This is the fastest way, however could be made cleaner. I would just separate printing from processing.

Comment: `print(" ".join("1" if word in tokens else "0" for word in tweet.split()))`

Comment: I just noticed the OP's example treats "`cool!`" as matching "`cool`". Thought you would like to know.

Comment: +1 because this is the way to go (except for `:)`), and for the lesser used `string.punctuation`. However, I agree with J.F. Sebastian: reading `str(int(…))` requires more mental gymnastics than his `"1" if … else "0"`, so it is less legible and I don't recommend it.

Comment: oh wow this is very elegant indeed! im surprised u i get responses for fast, what takes me a day, takes u a few mins! :) thanx so much, its going to take me a lil time to read/understand it, so i might have a few more questions soon...but it looks indeed elegant! thanx again!!!

Comment: The `:)` could be handled by adding `word in tokens or …` to the test. This would also speed the processing up a bit, since the most common case does not require stripping punctuation.

Comment: @EOL im not to sure what you mean by 'word in tokens or ...', could you maybe clarify that? I ask because ':)' will be in the list, seeing as it will show a positive sentiment more clearly than words itself.

Comment: @EOL thanx dudes!! obviously my list will contain many more words (about 20) and contain other 'emoticons' such as ':(' and '-_-' for negative tweets, but i can edit/append the list myself with these tokens. Also atm the tweet is hardcoded, but it will need to go through a text file that has about 5000 lines (tweets), i could just replace the tweet variable with a loop that reads each line?

Comment: @RHK-S8 no need to `sed` that. can remove the comma using `.strip(',')`. but this will not solve all you problems.

Comment: @RHK-S8: if you want to support the punctuation that can also be a part of a token; then a simple solution is just add `emoticon + punkt` to the token set e.g., to support both `(^.^)` (an emoticon) and `:).` (emoticon + punkt), you could add `:).` to the `tokens` without stripping `.` (dot) before hand. btw, to support tweets from a file, you could just `tweets = input_file` (a file is an iterable over lines in Python). To open file: `with open(filename) as input_file: ...`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian and Elazar....this was the wrong attempt at analysing my data, my apologies...i have re-asked the question on a different page, feel free to comment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804471/changing-lines-of-text-into-binary-type-pattern

Answer (score 1):

In `awk`:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    a[$1];
    next
    }

{ 
    gsub(/!/, "", $0)  # This will ignore `!`. Other rules can be added.
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i in a) {
        printf "1 "
        }
    else {
        printf "0 "
        }
    }
    print ""
}' lookup tweets
```

#### Test: (You'll probably need to alter `gsub` line to handle special cases.)

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat lookup
:)
cool
happy
fun

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat tweets
this has been a fun day :)
i find python cool! it makes me happy

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '
NR==FNR {
    a[$1];
    next
    }

{ 
    gsub(/!/, "", $0)
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i in a) {
        printf "1 "
        }
    else {
        printf "0 "
        }
    }
    print ""
}' lookup tweets
0 0 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you needed this as an all regex, then have a look at my solution here 
[Changing lines of text into binary type pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804471/changing-lines-of-text-into-binary-type-pattern/16804946#16804946)