# Changing lines of text into binary type pattern

Tags: python, regex

earlier this week i posted a question on how to change specific words to numbers in a file. As part of my sentiment analysis work. This was not the right method for me unfortunately, i interpreted my data wrong. So i will re ask the question using the right method.

I have a specific word list that contains tokens, for example purposes i will use 4 words eventhough it will be 40 words. I need to turn tweets into a 0 1 1 0 type format using a list to do so.

My list is as follows (a text file with 1 word per line):

- :)
- :(
- happy
- sad

my example tweets:

- TWEET1: I find python cool, it makes me happy :)
- TWEET2: today is a sad day :(

the output should be:

- TWEET1: 1 0 1 0
- TWEET2: 0 1 0 1

Basically every digit corresponds to where the token is found in the list. So in TWEET1, the first '1' corresponds to position one in the list (which is the smiley), the second digit '0', corresponds to position two in the list (unhappy smiley), and because it is NOT found in the tweet, it becomes a '0'. The third digit, which is a '1', corresponds to the third place in the list (happy), and because it is found in the tweet...it becomes a '1'.....I hope im explaining it well.

Im using python to write a lot of my scripts/programs to manipulate the text found in my files, so im looking for a python program to do this for me. Im quite new to python, so i was hoping someone could help me write a script to do this.

I hope ive explained it well enough, it took me a while to grasp the concept myself.

thanx :)

MORE INFO:

- since my word list will be about 40 words, the output for every tweet will be atleast 40 digits. E.g.

0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0

**EDITED PART**

The amazing answer given below, does not suit the criteria. It replaces words with a digit very elegantly. But not what i need unfortuntately....

further explanation (the way it helped me understand it better).....

consider this:

TWEET1: "today is going to be a happy day :)"

- before it reads the line, the code is set to '0 0 0 0'
- it then checks the first '0' ......which means: check the first token in the list (smiley)...can it be found anywhere in the tweet? answer: yes. therefore the code becomes....'1 0 0 0'
- next we move to the second '0' (corresponds to unhappy face).....can we find unhappy face anywhere in the tweet? Answer: No....therefore 2nd digit stays '0'....our code is now '1 0 0 0'
- next we move to the 3rd digit, which corresponds to the word 'happy'. Can this word be found anywhere in the tweet? Answer: yes......our code now becomes '1 0 1 0'
- now we move to the last digit, corresponds to the word/token 'sad'......can this be found anywhere in the tweet? Answer: no......therefore last digit remains '0'
- our final code becomes '1 0 1 0'

i hope this explains it better :)

NOTE: the code corresponds to the word list, not to the words in the tweet.

Comment: Tip: don't forget to think through whether you want the tweet "Today the ambassador received the microfilm" to return `1` because it contains "sad" or not.

Comment: yeh good tip, it needs to be a unique word. Im still very lost, i dont even know where to start, or how to approach my whole task

Comment: @RHK-S8: You might want to start with tokenizing the tweets, as a separate function. That means extracting separate words. This can be done simply or more complex including taking care of grammar etc. But that's really a separate question.

Comment: To see examples of different tokenization methods, you could [look at `nltk.tokenize`](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html). You also might find http://help.sentiment140.com/ interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
wordlist = [':)', ':(', 'happy', 'sad']
tweets = ['I find python cool, it makes me happy :)', 'today is a sad day :(']
for tweet in tweets:
    print(' '.join(['1' if word in tweet else '0' for word in wordlist]))
```

Output:

```
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
```

Comment: thats actually how far i got last time, so unfortunately it doesnt help me much :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755598/best-way-to-change-words-into-numbers-using-specific-word-list?rq=1 ................. your response is similar to the reactions i got on my other post, atleast thats what it looks like :(

Comment: however, that was the wrong output/attempt at analysing my data

Comment: @RHK-S8: The response is similar because the question is almost the same. I see that you have changed the question slightly, which makes things easier, which is why this answer is simpler. I've tested it, and it works.

Comment: @RHK-S8: Because I made a complete answer to make sure I was correct, I now paste it here, just to prove to you that I'm right. This also of course removes your chance to actually learn anything useful, as you would have if you had did it yourself, but that's your loss. ;-)

Comment: i completely agree with your response, in normal cases i would take the time indeed...however my laptop was stolen, including my USB stick with the data i had originally annotated, so due to lack of time and diverting my resources, i saw no other option. I really appreciated your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

## Description

If you have to do this with regular expressions I'd do this in two parts.

**Part 1** would find and replace all the known words with a `1`.  Read your known word file into an array, then join the array with the regex or symbol `|`. Then nest that string into the regex.

`(?<=^|\s)(\b(?:happy|kittens|[:][)])\b\W?)(?=\s|$)`

[image]

**Part 2** goes back and replaces all the non-`1`'s with a `0`.

`(?<=^|\s)\b(1[^\s]+|[^1]|[^\s]{2,})\b(?=\s|$)`

[image]

## Example

I don't know python, but here is a php example of how this would look.

```
<?php
$sourcestring="I really like kittens, they make me happy.";
echo preg_replace('/(?<=^|\s)(\b(?:happy|kittens|[:][)])\b\W?)(?=\s|$)/i',' 1 ',$sourcestring);
?>

$sourcestring after replacement:
I really like 1 they make me 1



<?php
$sourcestring="I really like 1 they make me 1";
echo preg_replace('/(?<=^|\s)\b(1[^\s]+|[^1]|[^\s]{2,})\b(?=\s|$)/im',' 0 ',$sourcestring);
?>

$sourcestring after replacement:
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

## Summary

1. part 1

   - `(?<=^|\s)` lookbehind to ensure the word has either white space or a start of  a string
   - `(` start capture group  1
   - `\b` consume word boundary
   - `(?:` start non capture group
   - `happy|kittens|[:][)]` match the words happy, kittens, or :) respectively
   - `)` close the non capture group
   - `\b` consume word boundary
   - `\W?` capture any additional non white space character, this eats a punctuation mark
   - `)` close capture group 1
   - `(?=\s|$)` require a word has a space or end of string at the end
2. part 2

   - `(?<=^|\s)` lookbehind to ensure the word has either white space or a start of  a string
   - `\b` consume word boundary
   - `(` start capture group 1
   - `1[^\s]+` consume `1` followed by anynumber of non white space characters, this prevents preveiously matched/replaced `1`'s from being pickedup
   - `|` or
   - `[^1]` consume a single character providing it's not a `1`
   - `|` or
   - `[^\s]{2,}` 2 or more non white space characters
   - `)` close capture group 1
   - `\b` consume word boundary
   - `(?=\s|$)` require a word has a space or end of string at the end

## Disclaimer

This solution may fail if the input string contained `1` and if `1` wasn't part of your input string. You may want to consider doing a split on the delimited whitespace and then applying logic against the returned array.

Comment: What generated that figure?

Comment: I'm using debuggex.com . Although it doesn't support lookbehinds it's still handy for understanding the expression flow. There is also regexper.com. They do a pretty good job too, but it's not real time as you're typing.

Comment: wow! this looks amazing, but i think you misinterpreted the question. This part answers my previous post...i acutually thought i had to do it this way as well...lemme edit my post...give me a few mins, although i suspect were not far off the answer now

Comment: @Denomales have a look at the edited part, i hope this explains it better.

Comment: Your edit makes a wholesale change to how this would work. Based on the edit, I suggest using a function. I'll add a separate answer

Answer (score 0):

## Description

I suggest running this as a function. But first you'd need to create a hashtable wherein the keys are the words you like to match and the values are all `0`. Then use that regex in a function to find the matching words and on all matches you'd update the hashtable value for the match to a `1`. Once that where complete you could join the values of the hash table together into a string

`(?<=^|\s)(\b(?:happy|kittens|[:][)])\b)\W?(?=\s|$)`

[image]

- `(?<=^|\s)` lookbehind to ensure the word has either white space or a start of  a string
- `(` start capture group  1
- `\b` consume word boundary
- `(?:` start non capture group
- `happy|kittens|[:][)]` match the words happy, kittens, or :) respectively
- `)` close the non capture group
- `\b` consume word boundary
- `)` close capture group 1
- `\W?` capture any additional non white space character, this eats a punctuation mark, probaly useless but allows for additional checking
- `(?=\s|$)` require a word has a space or end of string at the end

## Example

I don't know python, so here is how I'd do it in Powershell as an example of how the logic works to show the regular expression.

```
$Words = @("happy", "kittens", "[:][)]")
$Tweet = "I really like kittens, they make me happy."

# build hashtable for each word
[hashtable]$WordHash = @{}
foreach ($Word in $Words) {
    $WordHash[$Word] = "0"
    } # next word

# find each known word and document find it
$Regex = "(?<=^|\s)(\b(?:" + $($Words -join "|") + ")\b)\W?(?=\s|$)"
Write-Host "regex:  $Regex"
    ([regex]$Regex).matches($Tweet) | foreach {
        $WordHash[$_.Groups[1].Value] = "1"
        } # next match

$WordHash[$Words] -join " "

yields
regex:  (?<=^|\s)(\b(?:happy|kittens|[:][)])\b)\W?(?=\s|$)
1 1 0
```

Comment: i dont have to use python specifically, i can use anything i want. Its just so i can prep my data for machine learning (SVM). So a program written in any language is welcome. let me have a read of your response :)

Comment: when you say powershell...u simply mean executing these lines of code within my unix shell, right?

Comment: powershell is the new-ish windows shell language, from a windows command prompt you can type powershell, then when the shell loads you can paste those lines into the console

Comment: how would i edit this into a loop, that interates through my textfile known as "tweets.txt" and saves it to a new file called "new-tweets.txt"?